# passwd -S gives "Alternate authentication scheme in use." and password in /etc/shadow not encrypted

Tags: centos, users, passwd

I created a new user using useradd utility and then modified the user to add password to it.  I am unable to understand what does "Alternate authentication scheme in use." mean. Also how to update the user so that it updates to `Password set, SHA512 crypt.` status.

Also while doing this I saw that password in `/etc/shadow` is not encrypted. Did I miss anything while adding password? Shouldn't this be implicit action by the system?

`useradd user`

`passwd -S user`

`user LK 2016-12-24 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)`

`usermod -p "Password"`

`user PS 2016-12-24 0 99999 7 -1 (Alternate authentication scheme in use.)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to use `usermod -p` you have to pass an encrypted password to it.
from `man pages`:

> -p, --password PASSWORD
>
> ```
> The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).
> ```

There is many way to get an encrypted password. for example using `openssl`:

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt xyz  yourpass
```

If you want to update user password to `SHA512` just use `passwd`, but, first make sure that your system use `SHA512` encrypt method

Two place you have to check:

**/etc/login.defs**

```
ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-password**

```
password [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

Comment: cool.. I figured the passwd and login.defs file but I did not know about the common-password file.

Answer (score 0):

Updating password using passwd seems to fix the entire situation. I am guessing usermod is not the correct way to add a password to a user we just created.